# How to Add/Delete new MANY_MANY relation

Tags: php, yii

How to Add/Delete new `MANY_MANY` relation in Yii? 
For Example i have a many-to many relation with users and projects. And the relations are set in the table `'project_user_assignment'`. I needed to add/Edit/Remove the relations from the table `'project_user_assignment'`.

**User Model**

```
 public function relations()
  {
    return array('projects' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Project', 'project_user_assignment(user_id, project_id)'),
        );
 }
```

**Project Model**

```
 public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'users' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', 'project_user_assignment(project_id, user_id)'),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Model for project_user_assignment table that way you can use the model to add/delete/edit the records

Comment: Is it possible to do the add/delete/edit without creating the 'project_user_assignment table' Model ?

Comment: You can use CActiveRecordBehavior to  automatically save/delete MANY_MANY relation objects when you save/delete an object , in your case , you might want to add behaviors in user & project model, take a look at this extension [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/advancedrelationsbehavior/)